# Inspecting Web View of an app that's not mine IOS

Tags: ios, webview, web-inspector

I've just downloaded an app from the app store, and I've seen some interesting web content that I'd like to inspect. I can't manage to do that in Safari on the desktop, probably because the app is not mine.

Is there a way to do that? I can jailbreak if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with a debugging proxy server such as Fiddler

Have a look here for info on configuring Fiddler and iOS together

http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForiOS